# Parsing XML in laravel: get @attributes value

Tags: php, xml, laravel-5

I have a XML file with account information I need to be loaded in my user's table in my database.

I found this package for Laravel for XML parsing:

https://github.com/orchestral/parser

I came thus far that I can load my XML but now I am stuck. Here's the code:

```
$xml = XmlParser::load(url('/xml/DEBTORS.xml'));
    dd($xml);
    $user = $xml->parse([
       'Name' => ['uses','Accounts.Account.Name'],
    ]);
```

$user Name returns NULL

[image]

Part of the XML for example:

```
<Account code="1004" status="A" type="C">
 <Name>example name here</Name>
 <Phone>emaple phone here</Phone>
```

For example I want to reach Account Code in @attributes and assign that to ID.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `i found this package for laravel`. Which package?

Comment: Added @Abhishek

Comment: With `SimpleXMLElement`s you can get attributes as indices, e.g. `$accounts->Account[0]["code"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml = XmlParser::load(url('/xml/DEBTORS.xml'));
$user = $xml->parse([
   'Name' => ['uses','Accounts.Account.Name'],
   'Id'   => ['uses','Accounts.Account::code']
]);
```

From [doc](https://github.com/orchestral/parser#xml-document-parser-for-laravel-and-php)